# How can I unittest wsgi code which uses gevent?

Tags: python, wsgi, gevent

I'd like to test my WSGI library with gevent's WSGI Servers to ensure that request parameters aren't leaked/overwritten with those from another request/greenlet - in my library `request` is "global", though it *should* be thread-safe... which is what I'd like to test using gevent.

What approaches can I use? Are there any open-source projects which already have unittests which achieve this from which I could learn?

Comment: HI unpluggd, did you see this page: http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html

Answer (score 1):

If your library uses threading.local to provide thread-isolated "global" request variable then all you need is to call gevent.monkey.patch_thread BEFORE you use threading.local. That should turn all threading.local objects into "greenlet.local" ones.